# Spring 5 how to use Log4jConfigListener

Tags: spring, log4j, logback

In the past, i used to spring 4.3.8 version, 
i used to Log4j  config in web.xml like below code,

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/log4j-${spring.profiles.active}.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Currently, i trying to use spring 5.0.7 version but, i can't use Log4jConfigListener

i realized Log4jConfigListener is not exist in spring 5.x version

I can use "log4j.xml"(default name) but i want to use custom name for sever,local environment

how can i do?

Answer (score 6):

Just Remove the listener from web.xml and put log4j.properties file in your classpath. then you will get your result.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Log4jConfigListener`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html) has been removed as of Spring 4.2.1, in favor of Apache Log4j 2.

See the relevant information [Spring 4.2.1 deprecation list](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.1.RELEASE/deprecated-list.html):

> org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
>
> as of Spring 4.2.1, in favor of Apache Log4j 2 (following Apache's EOL declaration for log4j 1.x)

You can configure environments in the XML file using [Environment Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html).

Comment: Any concrete example of how I can use "Environment Lookup" to replace Log4jConfigListener?

Answer (score 4):

org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener is deprecated 
as of Spring 4.2.1, in favor of Apache Log4j 2 (following Apache's EOL declaration for log4j 1.x)

as an alternate you can change your configuration to use 
org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener (log4j-web)
More details can be found here
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html